# In Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2010, how can I modify where a dll is registered during a install?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dll

I build an install file that includes XML and a few other programs. Right now I am getting the following message during an attempted install of my files:

> msxml4.dll failed to register. HRESULT -2147023782. Contact your support personnel.

This is because I actually need to register MSXML4 on regsvr32 for my install.

Manually I can do the following:

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\regsvr32 C:\User\Desktop\msxml4.dll
```

However, I would like to do so automatically by modifying my Visual Studio set up package before I build it through a Custom Action or anything else that would get the job done.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: you need to be an admin to do that.

Comment: I can get admin status. What would be next?

Answer (score 0):

Administrative rights are required for assembly registration.

Comment: I have admin rights. What is the best way to modify the assembly code in visual studio specifically for the registration of a dll?

Comment: Flagging the assembly as needing registration should be good enough on the VS side.  During the install side of the package, the user needs to have admin rights.  The only other source of a failed registration are dependent assemblies missing.  I'm not sure if msxml4.dll has dependent assemblies that are needed for the registration process.

Comment: When you say "flagging the assembly", do you mean debugging the ASM for the code or is that a reference to a specific tool within VS?